# Trouble to apply PyPlot in JuliaPro v0.6.1.1

Tags: matplotlib, julia, package

Right after installing JuliaPro I started Juno. Then I typed

> using PyPlot.

I got the message:

> **No working GUI backend found for matplotlib**

To test if I have a Qt package:

> using PyCall
>
> pygui(:qt)

**:qt**

The next inputs are:

> ENV["PYTHON"]="";
>
> Pkg.build("PyCall");

lots of output

then

> using PyPlot
>
> x  =  linspace(0,2pi,200);  y  =  sin.(x+2*cos.(x));
>
> plot(x,y,color="red",linewidth=2.0,linestyle="--")

A window pops up with the message:

**This application failed to start because it could not find or
load the Qt platform plugin 'windows‘ ....**

Any help is appropriated.

Comment: I checked on a Windows 10 install of standard Julia 0.6.0 and it's using `:qt5`. I hadn't intentionally installed any backend either although maybe it came with some other open source software I installed prior to Julia.

The only other thing I could think of would be to delete PyPlot and reinstall. Reinstalling has worked for me in regards to another problem in the past.

Comment: removing PyPlot and reinstalling doesn't work. Meanwhile I'm a little desperate. I tested a lot of different hints but all attempts failed.Including uninstalling JuliaPro and reinstalling. Also I tried to steup the system loading Juliav0.6.1, Atom and Anaconda. Again no success.

Comment: Give `:qt5` a try if you haven't already. I'm installing PyPlot on an ancient Windows machine right now so maybe I'll have more incite soon.

Comment: The version of Julia was at 0.4 so the version of Anaconda was from that time. After installing Julia 0.6.1 I had to switch the python environment to `ENV["python"] = "python"` which refers to my Anaconda installation. Anaconda had matplotlib 1.4.x. After I rebuilt PyCall and PyPlot, `Pkg.build("PyCall")` and `Pkg.build("PyPlot")`, PyPlot worked. `pygui()` returned `:tk`. Maybe you need a different version of Anaconda or a full on version of Python with matplotlib installed.

Comment: This same issue was also referenced here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/219

Comment: If you want to check things in Anaconda start it up and at the command prompt type the following: `import matplotlib`, `matplotlib.__version__`, and `matplotlib.rc_params()`. Look for the backend section to see what's there.